# DBCA "ORA-27102: out of memory" error during create database files

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have problem about creating database on our oracle server.
Oracle is installing successfully.
When I trying to create a database by Database Configuration Assistant. 
Progress Bar is stoping at %2 and memory usage is increasing.

### Server

```
Intel Xeon CPU E7-4860 @2.27GHZ 2.26Ghz
64 GB Ram
Windows Server 2008 R2 (Service Pack 1) 64-Bit Operation System
```

### Oracle

```
11g Release 2 (11.2) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-Bit)
```

Content of {Oracle Home}\cfgtoollogs\dbca\trace.log_OraDb11g_home1  file

http://pastebin.com/52Pcp5aL

Content of {Oracle Home}\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\trace.log  file

http://pastebin.com/ZT64jBfs

Here is the last last screen before "Out of memory" alert.
[image: Last screen before out of memory error]

- Other Informations:

  - Oracle is installing successfully
  - Instance is creating and database service is starting successfully.
  - {ORACLE_HOME}\oradata{UNIQUE_DATABASE_NAME}\  is empty! assistant can not create the database binary file.
  - I was logged in with Administrator account and disable UAC.
  - Starting all of executable files as "Run as Administrator"
  - oradata{UNIQUE_DATABASE_NAME} folder can be edited by Everyone.
  - I have reinstalled the operation sytem and oracle server many time :)

---

```
11g Release 2 (11.2) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-Bit) still giving error.
11g Release 2 (11.1) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-Bit) installed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

### This note is from Oracle documentation
"Problem Description

You are attempting to create a new database using Oracle Database Configuration
Assistant when your server has a very large unused memory.  You pick a typical
type of database creation and receive the following error:

ORA-27102: out of memory

The database creation fails.

### Solution Description

Pick Custom installation and keep on picking default values if you wish to or
change them upon your requirements until you reach the page where you have to
set your initialization parameters of the newly created database.  Lower the
numbers of shared_pool_size and block_buffers to a reasonable and appropriate
number that can suit your needs as well as your hardware abilities and continue
with the creation.  The database will be created successfully. Here is a simple
formula to assist you in calculating the size of the SGA depending on the
values you will be assigning for your initialization parameters in init.ora:

( ( db_block_size * db_block_buffers ) + log_buffer + shared_pool_size +
large_pool_size + java_pool_size ) / .9

### Explanation

The reason this problem is occuring is because when you have large memory
installed on the server and a large segment of this memory is unused, the
Oracle Database Configuration Assistant will pick a percentage (roughly 30%) of
your unused memory and swap spaces and calculate the SGA to use those 30% of
this unused space.  This calculated percentage may exceed your server hardware
capabilities and may even exceed your requirement on the newly created database."